# Vert.x WriteStream setWriteQueueMaxSize

Tags: vert.x

I am new for Vert.x. When I read writestream in the article from https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/ as following:

```
setWriteQueueMaxSize: set the number of object at which the write queue is
 considered full, and the method writeQueueFull returns true. Note that, 
when the write queue is considered full, if write is called the data will 
still be accepted and queued. The actual number depends on the stream 
implementation, for Buffer the size represents the actual number of bytes 
written and not the number of buffers.
```

especially this statement - "Note that, when the write queue is considered full, if write is called the data will still be accepted and queued.", from this statement, I have a few of questions:

(1) Is there any size limitation for writing to stream? I mean, such as event bus, how many messages can be written to event bus? Does it depend on memory? suppose I keep on writing messages to event bus and message doesn't be consumed, does it cause Out of Memory in Java?

(2) If there is some limitation for writing, where and how can I check default queue size? Such as, I want to know the default queue size of Vert.x KafkaProducer, where can I check it?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually three separate questions there, but I'll give it a shot anyway:

> Is there any size limitation for writing to stream?

That depends on the stream implementation. But I've yet to see one implementation that actually uses `WriteQueueMaxSize`

> how many messages can be written to event bus? Does it depend on memory?

EventBus is a special case. If nobody is consuming from EventBus, it will simply drop messages, so in such a trivial case, an infinite number could be written. But if there are consumers, and they're slow, yes, eventually you'll run out of memory. EventBus implementation currently doesn't do anything with `WriteQueueMaxSize`

> If there is some limitation for writing, where and how can I check default queue size? Such as, I want to know the default queue size of Vert.x KafkaProducer, where can I check it?

All Vert.x project are open source, so you'll usually find them on GitHub (or other open source repo, but I don't remember any that are not on GitHub, actually).

Particularly for Vert.x KafkaProducer, you can see the code here:

https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-kafka-client/blob/1720d5a6792f70509fd7249a47ab50b930cee7a7/src/main/java/io/vertx/kafka/client/producer/impl/KafkaProducerImpl.java#L217